# CSS Preloader won't transition to text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, preloader

I was following [this tutorial](https://ihatetomatoes.net/create-custom-preloading-screen/) and managed to create a css preloader.

However, the preloader won't work properly. It shows the loader, the bits work fine, but won't transition to the text bit. I don't know what I did wrong. I followed the tutorial, even copied over the CSS/JS code to my own script to confirm it wasn't working. It still wouldn't work.

Can you look over the code and please tell me what I did wrong? Thanks

PS: All these files are located in the same directory.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  setTimeout(function() {
    $('body').addClass('loaded');
    $('h1').css('color', '#222222');
  }, 3000);

});
```

```css
p {
  line-height: 1.33em;
  color: #7E7E7E;
}
h1 {
  color: #EEEEEE;
}
#loader-wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
}
#loader {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: -75px 0 0 -75px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #3498db;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 5+ */
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  /* Chrome, Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
  z-index: 1001;
}
#loader:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  bottom: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #e74c3c;
  -webkit-animation: spin 3s linear infinite;
  /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 5+ */
  animation: spin 3s linear infinite;
  /* Chrome, Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
}
#loader:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 15px;
  right: 15px;
  bottom: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #f9c922;
  -webkit-animation: spin 1.5s linear infinite;
  /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 5+ */
  animation: spin 1.5s linear infinite;
  /* Chrome, Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
  }
}
@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
  }
}
#loader-wrapper .loader-section {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 51%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #222222;
  z-index: 1000;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
  -ms-transform: translateX(0);
  /* IE 9 */
  transform: translateX(0);
  /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
}
#loader-wrapper .loader-section.section-left {
  left: 0;
}
#loader-wrapper .loader-section.section-right {
  right: 0;
}
/* Loaded */

.loaded #loader-wrapper .loader-section.section-left {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
  -ms-transform: translateX(-100%);
  /* IE 9 */
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1.000);
  transition: all 0.7s 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1.000);
}
.loaded #loader-wrapper .loader-section.section-right {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
  /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
  -ms-transform: translateX(100%);
  /* IE 9 */
  transform: translateX(100%);
  /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1.000);
  transition: all 0.7s 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1.000);
}
.loaded #loader {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
.loaded #loader-wrapper {
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
  /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
  -ms-transform: translateY(-100%);
  /* IE 9 */
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s 1s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.3s 1s ease-out;
}
/* JavaScript Turned Off */

.no-js #loader-wrapper {
  display: none;
}
.no-js h1 {
  color: #222222;
}
#content {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 978px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./preloader.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="loader-wrapper">
    <div id="loader"></div>

    <div class="loader-section section-left"></div>
    <div class="loader-section section-right"></div>

    <div id="content">
      <h2>This is our page title</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="./preloader.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: did you add the jQuery?

Comment: It didn't tell me to, so no. Am I supposed to?

Comment: yes you have too, check answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After including jQuery

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
```

Above

```
<script src="./preloader.js"></script>
```

You can read [About jQuery](https://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/), why jQuery needed and how jQuery script works so down the road you can debug these small problems by yourself

Working Example (Don't need to change anything else)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  setTimeout(function() {
    $('body').addClass('loaded');
    $('h1').css('color', '#222222');
  }, 3000);

});
```

```css
p {
  line-height: 1.33em;
  color: #7E7E7E;
}
h1 {
  color: #EEEEEE;
}
#loader-wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
}
#loader {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: -75px 0 0 -75px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #3498db;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 5+ */
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  /* Chrome, Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
  z-index: 1001;
}
#loader:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  bottom: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #e74c3c;
  -webkit-animation: spin 3s linear infinite;
  /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 5+ */
  animation: spin 3s linear infinite;
  /* Chrome, Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
}
#loader:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 15px;
  right: 15px;
  bottom: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #f9c922;
  -webkit-animation: spin 1.5s linear infinite;
  /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 5+ */
  animation: spin 1.5s linear infinite;
  /* Chrome, Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
  }
}
@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
  }
}
#loader-wrapper .loader-section {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 51%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #222222;
  z-index: 1000;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
  -ms-transform: translateX(0);
  /* IE 9 */
  transform: translateX(0);
  /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
}
#loader-wrapper .loader-section.section-left {
  left: 0;
}
#loader-wrapper .loader-section.section-right {
  right: 0;
}
/* Loaded */

.loaded #loader-wrapper .loader-section.section-left {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
  -ms-transform: translateX(-100%);
  /* IE 9 */
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1.000);
  transition: all 0.7s 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1.000);
}
.loaded #loader-wrapper .loader-section.section-right {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
  /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
  -ms-transform: translateX(100%);
  /* IE 9 */
  transform: translateX(100%);
  /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1.000);
  transition: all 0.7s 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1.000);
}
.loaded #loader {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
.loaded #loader-wrapper {
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
  /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
  -ms-transform: translateY(-100%);
  /* IE 9 */
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s 1s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.3s 1s ease-out;
}
/* JavaScript Turned Off */

.no-js #loader-wrapper {
  display: none;
}
.no-js h1 {
  color: #222222;
}
#content {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 978px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./preloader.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="loader-wrapper">
    <div id="loader"></div>

    <div class="loader-section section-left"></div>
    <div class="loader-section section-right"></div>

    <div id="content">
      <h2>This is our page title</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./preloader.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Preloader works fine now. Quick question: Why does the text get pushed up and disappear once the page has loaded? It happens when I run the snippet here, and when I copy the code into my HTML. Is there a line of code that I've accidentally added on there that does this? If so, would you mind highlighting it? Thanks.

Comment: Ah. Apparently it had something to do with the "content" div, so I just moved my text out of that and it worked. Dunno if that was the correct solution, but it seems to have worked.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is in your js you are using selectors and methods from jquery like `$`, `.addClass`, `.css` and for using it you have to include jQuery

```
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js
```

Check out this http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_selectors.asp

or you can doit with pure javascript like this:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.querySelector("body").className = "loaded"; 
    document.querySelector("h1").style.color = "#222222";
  }, 3000);

});
```

```css
p {
  line-height: 1.33em;
  color: #7E7E7E;
}
h1 {
  color: #EEEEEE;
}
#loader-wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
}
#loader {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: -75px 0 0 -75px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #3498db;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 5+ */
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  /* Chrome, Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
  z-index: 1001;
}
#loader:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  bottom: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #e74c3c;
  -webkit-animation: spin 3s linear infinite;
  /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 5+ */
  animation: spin 3s linear infinite;
  /* Chrome, Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
}
#loader:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 15px;
  right: 15px;
  bottom: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #f9c922;
  -webkit-animation: spin 1.5s linear infinite;
  /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 5+ */
  animation: spin 1.5s linear infinite;
  /* Chrome, Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
  }
}
@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
  }
}
#loader-wrapper .loader-section {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 51%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #222222;
  z-index: 1000;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
  -ms-transform: translateX(0);
  /* IE 9 */
  transform: translateX(0);
  /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
}
#loader-wrapper .loader-section.section-left {
  left: 0;
}
#loader-wrapper .loader-section.section-right {
  right: 0;
}
/* Loaded */

.loaded #loader-wrapper .loader-section.section-left {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
  -ms-transform: translateX(-100%);
  /* IE 9 */
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1.000);
  transition: all 0.7s 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1.000);
}
.loaded #loader-wrapper .loader-section.section-right {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
  /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
  -ms-transform: translateX(100%);
  /* IE 9 */
  transform: translateX(100%);
  /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1.000);
  transition: all 0.7s 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1.000);
}
.loaded #loader {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
.loaded #loader-wrapper {
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
  /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
  -ms-transform: translateY(-100%);
  /* IE 9 */
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s 1s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.3s 1s ease-out;
}
/* JavaScript Turned Off */

.no-js #loader-wrapper {
  display: none;
}
.no-js h1 {
  color: #222222;
}
#content {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 978px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./preloader.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="loader-wrapper">
    <div id="loader"></div>

    <div class="loader-section section-left"></div>
    <div class="loader-section section-right"></div>

    <div id="content">
      <h2>This is our page title</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="./preloader.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I really recommend you to add jquery and avoid you having to do everything with pure javascript.